# yii2 Removing a model from ActiveDataProvider

Tags: model, yii2

I have an `ActiveDataProvider` which includes several models. Now I need to remove one of these models. Let's say my `ActiveDataProvider` called `$allproducts` has 6 models. Now I need to remove model 4 from `$allproducts`. How can I achieve this?

I am trying to loop in the ActiveDataProvider and in case of some condition, remove the model. In my example Model 4 (item Nr. 4) is marked for deleting.

```
foreach ($allproducts as $key => $product){
    if ($value == 'delete') {   // model 4, $value = 'delete'
        unset($allproducts[$key]);
    }
}
```

But I think this is not a proper way. Is there a specific way in yii2 to remove a model from an `ActiveDataProvider` object?

What is the right procedure?

Comment: why are you fetching that model in the query if you need to remove it

Comment: sorry, i dont understand it? What do you mean on that?

Comment: you are trying to remove a record returned by active dataprovider, i am saying that why do you fetch that record via activedataprovider if you have to remove it afterwards, why not filter it out before you return the dataprovider

Comment: It is a 'virtual' Dataprovider, based on the records of a datagridview. In the datagridview there is an editable column. If a change is made in the column, a controller action will be called. In this controller function I have to add a 'virtual' row(model/item) to the ActiveDataProvider, or in case of deleting to remove the 'virtual' model from the ActiveDataProvider. After that, the Datagrid will be updated. Adding a 'virtual' row is doing fine, but removing, which removes a row from the datagrid, causes me some headache!

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1) change query adding necessary condition, for example:

```
$query = Model::find()->andWhere(['<>', 'value', 'deleted']);
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query
]);
```

2) get all models from ActiveDataProvider with $dataProvider->model, cycle returned array and remove unwanted item, such as:

```
$models = $dataProvider->models;
for($k=0;$k<count($models);$k++)
{
    if($models[$k]->value == 'deleted')
    {
        unset($models[$k]);
    }
}
```

I prefer the first, because it is more clear.

Comment: I do it similar like your second solution, because it is a virtual DataProvider. In this way Iam worried about the ActiveDataProvider, because the ActiveDataProvider has also a 'keys' element. I think I also have to remove the corresponding key? Furthermore, do I have to reorganize the keys when I'am deleting a model manuel with the unset methode?

Comment: After deleting model from $models, you can populate an ArrayDataProvider (instead ActiveDataProvider): $dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider(['allModels' => $models]); I think that this is the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Some may ask why doing this? why not just filter the data in query and then pass it to dataProvider? Here is why, some times you need to check something that is not MySQL related, maybe you want to call a model function to get a property that is not in the database. In that case, the best option would be something like my example:

```
if($dataProvider->count > 0){
    $me = Yii::$app->user->id;
    $models = $dataProvider->models;
    foreach($models as $k => $model){
        if(!in_array($me, $model->audienceUsers)){
            unset($models[$k]);
        }
    }
    $dataProvider->setModels($models);
}
```

Remember that you **cannot** directly unset a model from `$dataProvider->models`